# copy dictionary containing object to an array of objects c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Dictionary like `Dictionary<string,Object>`,is there any method of converting the Dictionary to an array of objects,where the class of the object will contain two members-one of which will be the string and the other will be the Object stored as the value-pair in the dictionary.Please help!!!..

Comment: Without more detail, you could have `dictionary.ToArray()`, which gives you precisely your description. Namely, an array of `KeyValuePair<string, object>`. What more would you like?

Comment: I want an array[] of objects of the following class:                  Class A { string,object}. Currently I have the Values in a dictionary Dictionary<string,object>,I do not want any other Collection Type other than array in my result set.The value pair in the dictionary contains an object of type collection,i want to convert even that collection to an array.

Answer (score 1):

`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` implements `IEnumerable<T>` where `T` is `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`. To flatten this to an array all that is necessary is to call `IEnuemrable<T>.ToArray` as such:

```
Dictionary<string, int> dict = new Dictionary<string, int>() { { "Key1", 0 }, { "Key2", 1 } };
var kvArray = dict.ToArray();
```

`kvArray` will then be an array objects that reference the keys and values of each element in `dict` as two separate members of the same object.

Your question is a bit ambiguous though, perhaps further explanation would help us figure out a more appropriate solution.

---

Re your comment, LINQ is good for that:

```
Dictionary<string, int[]> dict = new Dictionary<string, int[]>() { { "Key1", new int[] { 0, 1, 2 } }, { "Key2", new int[] { 4, 5, 6 } } };

var pairs = dict.SelectMany(pair => pair.Value
                .Select(v => 
                    new { 
                        Key = pair.Key, 
                        Value = v 
                    }
                 )
             );
```

Comment: The int variable in your example is a object of a collection in my case,I want to convert that to an array-->                             Dictionary<string,object of collection type class>--->to ----> Array[] of a class where class contains two members:             Member 1:string,Member 2: Array[]..the member 2 is a collection type of variable in the Dictionary...

Answer (score 0):

Given a class:

```
class ClassA
{
    string CustomerId { get; set; }
    PatientRecords[] Records { get; set; }

    public ClassA(string name, PatientRecords[] records)
    {
        Name = name;
        Records = records;
    }
}
```

I'm assuming that `CollectionOfPatientRecords` implements IEnumberable:

`var dict = new Dictionary<string, CollectionOfPatientRecords> ( ... );`

Then to get your array of ClassA with the right values:

```
dict.Select(kv => new ClassA(kv.Key, kv.Value.ToArray())).ToArray();
```

Comment: I have Dictionary<string, array_of_collectiontype> and want to convert it to Array[] of class A where Class A contains: Member 1:string,Member 2:Array of the class used in the dictionary's value pair

Comment: Class A { PatientRecords[],
CustomerID string} and the dictinary contains...Dictionary<customer ID,CollectionofPatientrecords>.What i want is Array of Class A from the dictionary.

Comment: Changed to give an example based on your class. Note that CollectionOfPatientRecords must implement IEnumberable. Vote or accept if it's what you wanted.